# Convert very large XLSX file to TSV on Mac

Tags: excel, macos, xlsx

I need to convert an arbitrarily large XLSX file to TSV. The file is 700MB and the following approaches have failed:

- LibreOffice crashes
- XLSX2TSV does not complete after one hour https://gist.github.com/brendano/22764
- https://github.com/brendano/tsvutils does not complete after one hour

I have unzipped the XLSX file and pretty printed the worksheet XML, but this is not an obvious task to grep it for the data.

What is a usable solution for converting this beast?

(Macbook Air, 4gb RAM, 20gb disk available)

Comment: If you can convert the XLS to Numbers, you can export to a CSV, and just batch replace commas to tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you need to convert it to TSV? Is it to be able to parse it more easily?

Trying to grep the worsheet XML is indeed not going to work, as the data can be split across different XML files (and grepping a very large file is not performant).

If your file only contains basic text (no charts, functions...), you can try Spout: https://github.com/box/spout. A 700MB file may take a loooong time (like hours) to be processed but at least it won't go out of memory.
Then the concern will be if you want to open this 700MB file in Excel or similar, you may end up crashing Excel because the file would require too much memory to be loaded...

Comment: I want TSV because I can grep TSV. Just tried spout. It did chug through my 200MB XLSX file in 6 hours without crashing. However the formatting was unusable, dates were saved as Excel date numbers rather than the format shown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. Install Wine from https://gist.github.com/brendano/22764
2. Acquire and install MS Office 2010
3. Do not complain about step #2

Here are some of the many attempts that did not work because they: lack usable documentation, run out of memory (on a 4GB system with nothing else running), freeze, and/or produce unusable output:

- LibreOffice (freezes on save)
- LibreOffice soffice command line (freezes)
- https://github.com/AndyStricker/FastXLSX (incomplete documentation, crashes)
- https://github.com/cool-hazcker/exceller
- https://github.com/leegao/pyXLSX
- https://github.com/staale/py-xlsx
- https://github.com/thirtyseven/dullard
- https://gist.github.com/brendano/22764
- https://github.com/box/spout (date output is not usable)